# Combine paho MQTT with another asyncio process in Python

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, mqtt

I have a basic MQTTListener class in Python which listens for messages on certain topics and should start or stop an async process imported from another script. This process runs forever, unless it is manually stopped. Let's assume the Listener looks like this:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
from python_file.py import async_forever_function

class MqttListener:

    def __init__(self, host, port, client_id):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client = mqtt.Client(client_id=self.client_id)
        self.client.connect(host=self.host, port=self.port)

    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):
        self.client.subscribe(topic=[("start", 1), ])
        self.client.subscribe(topic=[("stop", 1), ])
        logging.info(msg="MQTT - connected!")

    def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
        logging.info(msg="MQTT - disconnected!")

    def on_message(self, client, userdata, message, ):
        print('PROCESSING MESSAGE', message.topic, message.payload.decode('utf-8'), )

        if message.topic == 'start':
            async_forever_function(param='start')
            print('process started')
        else:
            async_forever_function(param='stop')
            print('process removed')

    def start(self):
        self.client.on_connect = lambda client, userdata, flags, rc: self.on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc)
        self.client.on_message = lambda client, userdata, message: self.on_message(client, userdata, message)
        self.client.on_disconnect = lambda client, userdata, rc: self.on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc)

        self.client.loop_start()

    def stop(self):
        self.client.loop_stop()
```

Now, this works for *starting* a new async process. That is, async_function is correctly triggered when a message is posted on the start MQTT topic. However, once this async process is started, the listener is no longer able to receive/process messages from the stop MQTT topic and the async process will continue to run forever, when in fact it should have been stopped.

**My question**: how can I adapt the code of this class such that it can also process messages when an active async process is running in the background?

Comment: Is `process started` printed when the start message arrived?

Comment: Edit the question to show the output so we can see what's logged

Comment: @hardillb I'm sorry, I misread your comment. No, process started is not printed, because the async process is still running.

Answer (score 1):

As hardillb said, if you block `on_message` your client, it will not be able to receive more incoming messages. So, you can write your code with asyncio-mqtt or write a daemon. The first choice has an Async behavior (i.e. coroutines) and it is more accessible than the second one. I wrote an example of both in Python. [Gist](https://gist.github.com/sanchezcarlosjr/1769cf2347c49823f3c5dd9ca07ee3b8).

Answer (score 0):

You can not do blocking tasks in the `on_message()` callback.

This call back runs on the MQTT client thread (the one started by the `loop_start()` function. This thread handles all network traffic and message handling, if you block it then it can't do any of that.

If you want to call long running tasks from the `on_message()` callback you need to start a new thread for the long running task so it doesn't block the MQTT client loop.

Comment: I tried implementing your suggesting with adding another loop, but I get *RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running*. I've tried to solve this, but cannot work it out. Could you perhaps edit your answer with the generic code from mine to show what you mean with starting a new thread?

Comment: No, you can't run "another" loop, you have to run your `async_forever_function` on it's own thread.

Comment: so, what is the solution?

Comment: @MarcoLettieri same as it was earlier. Start a fresh thread to run the blocking/long running task on.